# How long does it take to become KYC approved after submitting all documentation

Tags: transactions, assets, authorization

I have added a few assets that I would like to purchase and have submitted all of my KYC info on stellar.org How long does the KYC process take and do I need to do anything additional other than the form on stellar.org.